# How to convert from Unix epoch time and account for daylight saving time in Python?

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, data-conversion, python-datetime, epoch

I have a large database with thousands of records.  Each record contains a Unix epoch time.

The database was created in a single time zone, but that time zone has "daylight saving time" during which the local time is adjusted by an hour for several months.

In Python, I want to convert all those epoch times to the correct local time in that time zone, taking into account "daylight saving time".  I am new to Python.

**Important: Some of the dates were recorded during "daylight saving time" and some of the dates were recorded during "standard time".**

Currently, my code is:

```
import time
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time_from_database))
```

(where `time_from_database` is the Unix epoch time obtained from the database)

How can this be achieved in Python?

Comment: Epoch time doesn't account for DST; it linearly increases. DST offsets get applied when you convert from epoch time to a specific time zone. If the time in your database is adjusted for DST, it's not really epoch time.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. The time in the database is epoch time, but I need to convert it to the correct local time, which requires accounting for DST (or the lack of it) on each date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system has support for time zone conversions, and Python can use that. You don't need to handle it in your Python code.

You get to it using the *pytz* module. It is also preferred to use the datetime object.

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

MYTZ = "America/Los_Angeles"
TS = 1631491515.6691816

tzinfo = pytz.timezone(MYTZ)

t = datetime.fromtimestamp(TS, tzinfo)
print(t)
```

`2021-09-12 17:05:15.669182-07:00`

Comment: Thank you Keith!  Does the MYTZ variable need to match the time zone string as dictated by the OS on which the Python code is running, or are the time zone names now standard across all modern operating systems?

Comment: The names are standard. You should get it from the system config. On Linux it varies, but is usually in `/etc/timezone`.